# Extracting all but a certain sequence of characters in Bash

Tags: bash

In bash I need to extract a certain sequence of letters and numbers from a filename. In the example below I need to extract just the S??E?? section of the filenames. This must work with both upper/lowercase.

```
my.show.s01e02.h264.aac.subs.mkv
great.s03e12.h264.Dolby.mkv
what.a.fab.title.S05E11.Atmos.h265.subs.eng.mp4
```

Expected output would be:

```
s01e02
s03e12
S05E11
```

I've been trying to do this with SED but can't get it to work. This is what I have tried, without success:

```
sed 's/.*s[0-9][0-9]e[0-9][0-9].*//'
```

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: Are the file names in a text file?

Comment: Your pattern looks good. Maybe with grep like `echo $filename | grep -io 'S??E??'`

Comment: I've been trying the following with no luck 
sed 's/.*s[0-9][0-9]e[0-9][0-9].*//'

Comment: @TheSlater I think, you have the best approach. You should post this as an answer^^

Comment: @acran The problem is, when you're running with your smartphone, you don't dare to write an untested answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` we can match the desired string in a capture group, and use the `I` suffix for case-insensitive matching, to accomplish the desired result.

For the sake of this answer I'm assuming the filenames are in a file:

```
$ cat fnames
my.show.s01e02.h264.aac.subs.mkv
great.s03e12.h264.Dolby.mkv
what.a.fab.title.S05E11.Atmos.h265.subs.eng.mp4
```

One `sed` solution:

```
$ sed -E 's/.*\.(s[0-9][0-9]e[0-9][0-9])\..*/\1/I' fnames
s01e02
s03e12
S05E11
```

Where:

- `-E` - enable extended regex support
- `\.(s[0-9][0-9]e[0-9][0-9])\.` - match `s??e??` with a pair of literal periods as bookends; the `s??e??` (wrapped in parens) will be stored in capture group #1
- `\1` - print out capture group #1
- /`I` - use case-insensitive matching

Comment: Thanks for the reply. For some reason when I run it I get nothing back. Sure it's something I've done wrong. Do I need to install this extended support?

Comment: Got it. I has a typo. Many thanks for that spot on answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your pattern is ok. With the `grep -o` you get only the matched part of a string instead of matching lines. So

```
grep -io 'S[0-9]{2}E[0-9]{2}'
```

solves your problem. Compared to your pattern only numbers will be matched. Maybe you can put it in an if, so lines without a match show that something is wrong with the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have those file names:

```
$  ls -1
great.s03e12.h264.Dolby.mkv
my.show.s01e02.h264.aac.subs.mkv
what.a.fab.title.S05E11.Atmos.h265.subs.eng.mp4
```

You can extract the substring this way:

```
$ printf "%s\n" * | sed -E 's/^.*([sS][0-9][0-9][eE][0-9][0-9]).*/\1/'
```

Or with `grep`:

```
$ printf "%s\n" *.m* | grep -o '[sS][0-9][0-9][eE][0-9][0-9]'
```

Either prints:

```
s03e12
s01e02
S05E11
```

You could use that same `sed` or `grep` on a file (with filenames in it) as well.